# Customizing Google Chrome's bookmarks bar

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, favicon

I just installed Google Chrome 7, and I am frustrated with the behavior of the bookmarks bar. I am wondering if there are any ways to get the following behaviors:

1. I would like the bookmarks bar to always be visible, or at least appear when I hover around or click a button.
2. It doesn't show favicons. (It's a new install, so I think maybe I have to load all the pages for the favicons to load).
3. I would like to be able to show favicons only, and use the content as a tool-tip, no text (like this): [image: example]
4. The icons should be configurable for each weblink, like in Internet Explorer:
   [image: example]

**Update**
Based on the accepted answer, if anyone know about an extension that mimics IE's favorites-bar behavior (that at least has the option of "Show Icons Only" and shows the content as tooltips, please lemme know and I give Chrome another chance.

Comment: Your initial post had been nominated for closing due to subjectivity and lack of a proper question. I edited it in attempt to remove the subjective slant and emphasize the technological questions without the opinions. A clearly worded question without opinions and bias can help you get better answers. Best of luck finding a solution to your problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Right click the bookmarks bar, select *Always show bookmarks bar* on a *New Tab*.
2. It does show favicons, but if you've imported bookmarks, you may indeed need to access the sites for them to load. You could right click your bookmarks bar and select *open all bookmarks*. After this they should be retained.
3. When you add your bookmark, remove the name. This will display the favicon only. I expected a tooltip, but looking now, there may not be one. If it already exists, right click and choose *Edit...*, then remove the name.
4. I'm not aware if this is possible.

[image]

Comment: I guess the most compelling thing (3) will lead me to my conclusion: stick to IE till these requirements are fixed in Chrome. I pretty happy with IE anyway, I just wanted to try out Chrome and see what it is all about. Nah, not for me, and least not now.

Answer (score 1):

For your request for an extension I only found [Iconized Bookmarks Popup](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/npgonnihpamikjkfckpolamefpniicak). I know that isn't exaclty what you're looking for, but maybe it helps you.